# proving that -1 is square if p = 1 mod 4

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I have to find $gcd(x^{P-1}-1,x^2+1)$ in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}[X]$ for some prime number p in order to show that $-1$ is a square $\pmod p$ iff $p\equiv1\pmod4$. I really have no idea where to start. I don't see how to get the gcd given that p is not a number. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try calculating $\gcd(x^{2n} - 1, x^2 + 1)$ (actually working through the calculations) for $n=1,2,3,4$ and see if you can observe and understand a pattern there.

Comment: A very similar question, asking for the use of the same polynomial tools, was  [asked yesterday.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507383/problem-with-finding-the-gcd-in-the-field-of-polynomials-mod-p)

Comment: I think the duplicate candidate suggested by André is a better match here, so I used it.